# ASP.NET Controller adding 1 hour to date (format ISO 8601) sent in AJAX request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application that sends a date in ISO 8601 to my controller.  My controller receives the date as a parameter and casts it to a datetime.  The problem that I am having is that 1 hour is being added to the date.  I have written a very small amount of code that replicates my problem.

This is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public void ShowDate(DateTime NewEventStart)
    {
        int x = 0; //set a breakpoint here  

    }
}
```

This is my view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    //this is a date in ISO 8601 format
    start = "2014-07-07T06:30:00.000Z";    
    UpdateEvent(start);


});


function UpdateEvent(EventStart) {

    var dataRow = {        
        'NewEventStart': EventStart        
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/ShowDate/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataRow)
    });
}

</script>
```

When I run the above code and inspect the value of NewEventStart using the debug tools it says the time has changed to 07:30 when I would expect it to say 06:30.

I suspect that possibly some kind of time settings on my machine could be causing this or some kind of timezone issue?  Can someone see the problem and or a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date string is parsed to your local time zone.  If you want the UTC date (i.e. to match the date string your view), in your controller action method, use

```
NewEventStart = NewEventStart.ToUniversalTime();
```